# Cannot read innerHTML of undefined in selenium thought element is defined?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

During the execution of a python script utilizing Selenium and Chrome-driver, there was a particular issue in where the driver execute a java script segment then return:

`Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined`

This is the segment:

```js
function getCommand() {
                        var MSGNUM = document.getElementsByClassName("ChatBox").length -1;
                        var MSG = document.getElementsByClassName("message-body")[MSGNUM];
                        MSG = MSG.innerHTML;
                        var NAME = document.getElementsByClassName("username")[MSGNUM];
                        NAME = NAME.innerHTML;
                        var COMMAND = (NAME+" "+MSG);
                        return(COMMAND);
                    }
                    return getCommand(); //To return the statement back to a python varible
```

```html
<div class="ChatBox" style="display: block;">
<div class="Wrapper">
<div class="username">Chuck Norris</div>
<div class="message-body">Goodmorning</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the python code executing it

```
message = driver.execute_script("""    function getCommand() {
                        var MSGNUM = document.getElementsByClassName("ChatBox").length -1;
                        var MSG = document.getElementsByClassName("message-body")[MSGNUM];
                        MSG = MSG.innerHTML;
                        var NAME = document.getElementsByClassName("username")[MSGNUM];
                        NAME = NAME.innerHTML;
                        var COMMAND = (NAME+" "+MSG);
                        return(COMMAND);
                    }
                    returngetCommand()""");
```

The java script works without fault when executed in the google chrome command line, without the illegal return statement. Updating both chromedriver and selenium seem not to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wait some time until required element appeared in DOM. Also I see no reason to use `execute_script`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chat_box = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ChatBox")))[-1]
message = chat_box.find_element_by_class_name("message-body").text
name = chat_box.find_element_by_class_name("username").text
print(name + " " + message)
```